# Uber Needle DI use in Non Reactive Context

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

What is the best way to share data downstream with [uber/needle](https://github.com/uber/needle) in a non reactive context?

Let me provide a simple case. I have a comment list which has a corresponding Component and ViewController. User taps on a comment.
What would be a good way to pass this selected comment from the comment list ViewController back to the comment list Component (parent) so it can introduce a new dependency. The end goal being that the comment detail Component (child) can instantiate a comment detail ViewController for the selected comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the samples, the suggested approach would be to use a builder as dependency of the comment list VC

```
final class CommentListComponent: Component<CommentListDependency>, CommentListBuilder {

    private var commentDetailBuilder: CommentDetailBuilder {
        commentDetailComponent(parent: self)
    }

    var commentListViewController: UIViewController {
        CommentListViewController(commentDetailBuilder: self.commentDetailBuilder)
    }
}


protocol CommentListDependency: Dependency {
}


protocol CommentListBuilder {
    var commentListViewController: UIViewController
}
```

As you can see above, the comment list vc will get a reference to the builder, defined below:

```
final class CommentDetailComponent: Component<CommentDetailDependency>, CommentDetailBuilder {

    // CommentRef is either a model or an id to fetch it from a data store
    func commentDetailViewController(commentRef: CommentRef) -> UIViewController {
        CommentDetailViewController(commentRef: commentRef)
    }
}


protocol CommentDetailDependency: Dependency {
}


protocol CommentDetailBuilder {
    func commentDetailViewController(commentRef: CommentRef) -> UIViewController
}
```

On your comment list vc, once a comment is selected, you call the `commentDetailBuilder.commentDetailViewController(commentRef:)` method passing the reference to the selected comment to get a detail vc that you can then present.

You can see the same pattern in their MVC example where `GameComponent` injects a `scoreSheetBuilder` into `GameViewController`
https://github.com/uber/needle/blob/5d8c0854b95ac9449228410d4282b625c3ceb6be/Sample/MVC/TicTacToe/Sources/Game/GameComponent.swift